# Google calender Api date filter not working in apex

Tags: google-api, filtering, google-calendar-api

I am trying to fetch data only which resides on particular dates.I am using this api-:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events&timeMin=2021-10-25T10:00:00-07:00&timeMax=2021-10-28T10:00:00-07:00&timeZone=America/Los_Angeles
but this is not working.I am using apex so don't have library support.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, from your question, I proposed a modificaiton point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your URL, I thought that when the query parameter is added, it is required to modify from `/events&timeMin=` to `/events?timeMin=`. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2021-10-25T10:00:00-07:00&timeMax=2021-10-28T10:00:00-07:00&timeZone=America/Los_Angeles
```

- In this case, when the calendar is publicly shared, you can use this endpoint with the API key. When the calendar is not publicly shared, please use the access token retrieved by the OAuth2 and the service account.
- And, I'm worried that you might be required to use by converting the above URL by the URL encoding. At that time, please test this. `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMax=2021-10-28T10%3A00%3A00-07%3A00&timeMin=2021-10-25T10%3A00%3A00-07%3A00&timeZone=America%2FLos_Angeles`

#### Reference:

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)